# Python reasons for numpy nanpercentile being very slow compared to numpy percentile?

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

I want to compute a moving percentile over the first axis of a 4D array. First I created the rolling windows this via stacking rolled arrays along a new dimension, but later found that views via `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided()` are much (more than an order-of-magnitude) faster. Afterwards, I compute the percentile over the new axis. In order to have truncated windows near the edge while keeping the same window length, I padded the array with NaNs before obtaining the rolling windows, and then apply `np.nanpercentile()`. However, I noticed that `np.nanpercentile()` is very slow and tested it with the example code below.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import time

t = []
np.random.seed(100)

a = np.random.rand(26,72,73,273)
p = 0.7
for i in range(3):
    t.append(time.time())
    res_perc = np.percentile(a,p*100,axis=-1)
    t.append(time.time())
    res_nanperc = np.nanpercentile(a,p*100,axis=-1)
    t.append(time.time())
    print('compute percentile:', t[-2]-t[-3])
    print('compute nanpercentile:', t[-1]-t[-2])
```

**Output:**

```
compute percentile: 1.0262951850891113
compute nanpercentile: 24.713390827178955
compute percentile: 0.9878458976745605
compute nanpercentile: 24.505929470062256
compute percentile: 0.984771728515625
compute nanpercentile: 24.510523080825806
```

**Questions: How comes `np.nanpercentile()` is so much (> factor 20) slower than `np.percentile()`, even if there are actually no NaN values in the array?** Does the check whether there are any NaN values really take **that** long and why is that? The reason I am asking is that in my actual application, only 2 out of the 26 rolling windows in the first axis (those at the edges) will actually have contain NaNs, representing truncated windows. If I can actually save a factor of more than 20 for the remaining 24 rolling windows, I might just apply `np.percentile()` for those and `np.nanpercentile()` for the outer two rolling windows and then stitch the resulting values back together, significantly speeding up my code.

Comment: Look at the `np.nanpercentile` [source], and tell us if it's that simple.

Comment: Fair point, there's always some array copying going on, it seems...

Comment: Some of the `nan...` functions just replace the `nan` with something innocuous like `0` or `1`, or simply 'compress' it out.  But I suspect `percentile` has to do something more complex.  But I haven't thought much about what's involved.

Comment: Relevant: https://krstn.eu/np.nanpercentile()-there-has-to-be-a-faster-way/